# How do I get a count of values in an array, in a range or above a threshold value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I want to get a count of values greater than 350 and a second count of values greater than 510. I just need a single number for each count. I have seen some ways of getting counts, but they didn't appear to work for my purpose. Thanks for any help.

```
print(simfourty48)
[ array([  99.06,  180.15,  234.21,  369.36,  171.14,  162.13,   54.01,
        324.31,  171.14,  108.07,  225.2 ,  243.22,  306.29,  144.11,
        450.45,  693.72,  225.2 ,  486.49,  810.85,  243.22,  279.26,
        135.1 ,  261.24,  405.4 ,  126.09,  261.24,  162.13,  234.21,   45.  ])]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [`numpy.count_nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html)?

```
np.count_nonzero(simfourty48 > 350)
np.count_nonzero(simfourty48 > 510)
```

---

Actually, looking at `simfourty48`, it *looks* like you have a `list` whose only element is an `np.ndarray`.  In that case it would be:

```
np.count_nonzero(simfourty48[0] > 350)
```

But I'd recommend rethinking the list with 1 array datastructure if possible.  That seems like it will just end up making your life more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(filter(lambda x: x > 350, simfourty48))
```

Comment: This code doesn't run as is because I forgot to mention that the array is built from a list ( I didn't realize it matter until after the fact). corrected: sum(filter(lambda x: x > 350, simfourty48[0])); however, this just returns the values that meet the criteria and not a count of the values.